# spring boot register error using html code and spring boot. I can't continue the register process after clicking submit i got this error

Tags: html, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security, backend

> **this is the error message that appeared after clicking on the submit button on the register page**

Wed Aug 10 14:48:00 CET 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
rawPassword cannot be null

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rawPassword cannot be null
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(BCryptPasswordEncoder.java:107)
    at almanara.almanaraplateforme.web_signin_signup.Controller.LoginController.registerPost(LoginController.java:42)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


**

> this is the user entity that i used for the register form here you can find the attributes getters and setters etc...

**
```

````java
        @Entity
        @Table(name =  "utilisateurs")
        public class Utilisateur {
            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private Long idUtl;
            @NotBlank(message = "le nom est obligatoire")
            private String nomUtl;
            @NotBlank(message = "le prenom est obligatoire")
            private String prenomUlt;
            @NotEmpty
            @Length(min = 8, message = "le mot de passe doit contenir au minimum 8 chracteres")
            private String passwordUtl;
            //@NotBlank(message = "le numero telephone est obligatoire")
            @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
            private Long telUtl;
            @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
            @NotEmpty
        
            @Email(message = "{erros.invalid_email}")
            private String email;
            private String adresseUtl;
        
            private String emploiUtl;
            @NotBlank(message = "la region est obligatoire")
        
            private String regionUtl;
            @NotBlank(message = "le secteru d'activite est obligatoire")
        
            private String secteuractiviteUtl;
            //private boolean isAgriculteur = false;
           @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
            @JoinTable(
                    name = "utilisateurs_roles",
                    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                            name = "utilisateurs_id", referencedColumnName = "idUtl"),
                    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                            name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
        
            private List<Role> roles;
        
            public Set<Produit> getProduits() {
                return produits;
            }
        
            public void setProduits(Set<Produit> produits) {
                this.produits = produits;
            }
        
            @JsonIgnore
            @OneToMany(mappedBy = "utilisateur")
            private Set<Produit> produits = new HashSet<>();
       
    
        public Utilisateur() {super();}
        
            public Utilisateur(
                               String nomUtl,
                               String prenomUlt,
                             @NotEmpty  String passwordUtl,
                               Long telUtl,
                             @NotEmpty @Email(message = "{erros.invalid_email}") String email,
                               String adresseUtl,
                               String emploiUtl,
                               String regionUtl,
                               String secteuractiviteUtl,
                               List<Role> roles) {
        
                this.nomUtl = nomUtl;
                this.prenomUlt = prenomUlt;
                this.passwordUtl = passwordUtl;
                this.telUtl = telUtl;
                this.email = email;
                this.adresseUtl = adresseUtl;
                this.emploiUtl = emploiUtl;
                this.regionUtl = regionUtl;
                this.secteuractiviteUtl = secteuractiviteUtl;
               this.roles = roles;
            }
            public Utilisateur(Utilisateur utilisateur) {
        
                this.nomUtl = utilisateur.getNomUtl();
                this.prenomUlt = utilisateur.getPrenomUlt();
                this.passwordUtl = utilisateur.getPasswordUtl();
                this.telUtl = utilisateur.getTelUtl();
                this.email = utilisateur.getEmail();
                this.adresseUtl = utilisateur.getAdresseUtl();
                this.emploiUtl = utilisateur.getEmploiUtl();
                this.regionUtl = utilisateur.getRegionUtl();
                this.secteuractiviteUtl = utilisateur.getSecteuractiviteUtl();
                this.roles = utilisateur.getRoles();
            }
        
        
            public Utilisateur(String nomUtl,
                               String prenomUlt,
                             @NotEmpty  String passwordUtl,
                               Long telUtl,
                               @NotEmpty @Email String email,
                               String adresseUtl,
                               String emploiUtl,
                               String regionUtl,
                               String secteuractiviteUtl) {
                this.nomUtl = nomUtl;
                this.prenomUlt = prenomUlt;
                this.passwordUtl = passwordUtl;
                this.telUtl = telUtl;
                this.email = email;
                this.adresseUtl = adresseUtl;
                this.emploiUtl = emploiUtl;
                this.regionUtl = regionUtl;
                this.secteuractiviteUtl = secteuractiviteUtl;
            }
        
            public String getPassword() {
                return passwordUtl;
            }
        
            public String getUsername() {
                return email;
            }
        
            public boolean isAgriculteur() {
                return isAgriculteur;
            }
        
            public void setAgriculteur(boolean agriculteur) {
                isAgriculteur = agriculteur;
            }
        
            public Long getIdUtl() {
                return idUtl;
            }
        
            public void setIdUtl(Long idUtl) {
                this.idUtl = idUtl;
            }
        
            public String getNomUtl() {
                return nomUtl;
            }
        
            public void setNomUtl(String nomUtl) {
                this.nomUtl = nomUtl;
            }
        
            public List<Role> getRoles() {
                return roles;
            }
        
            public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
                this.roles = roles;
            }
        
            public String getPrenomUlt() {
                return prenomUlt;
            }
        
            public void setPrenomUlt(String prenomUlt) {
                this.prenomUlt = prenomUlt;
            }
        
            public String getPasswordUtl() {
                return passwordUtl;
            }
        
            public void setPasswordUtl(String passwordUtl) {
                this.passwordUtl = passwordUtl;
            }
        
            public Long getTelUtl() {
                return telUtl;
            }
        
            public void setTelUtl(Long telUtl) {
                this.telUtl = telUtl;
            }
        
        
            public String getEmail() {
                return email;
            }
        
            public void setEmail(String emailUtl) {
                this.email = emailUtl;
            }
        
            public String getAdresseUtl() {
                return adresseUtl;
            }
        
            public void setAdresseUtl(String addresseUtl) {
                this.adresseUtl = addresseUtl;
            }
        
            public String getEmploiUtl() {
                return emploiUtl;
            }
        
            public void setEmploiUtl(String emploiUtl) {
                this.emploiUtl = emploiUtl;
            }
        
            public String getRegionUtl() {
                return regionUtl;
            }
        
            public void setRegionUtl(String regionUtl) {
                this.regionUtl = regionUtl;
            }
        
            public String getSecteuractiviteUtl() {
                return secteuractiviteUtl;
            }
        
            public void setSecteuractiviteUtl(String secteuractiviteUtl) {
                this.secteuractiviteUtl = secteuractiviteUtl;
            }
    
    ```
this the login controller for the register and the login here are the POST and GET 
    ```java
        @Controller
        public class LoginController {
        
            @Autowired
            private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
            @Autowired
            UtilisateurRepo utilisateurRepo;
            @Autowired
            RoleRepo roleRepo;
            @GetMapping("/login")
            public String login(){
                GlobalData.cart.clear();
                return "login";
            }
            @GetMapping("/register")
            public String registerGet(){
                return "register";
            }
            @PostMapping("/register")
            public String registerPost(@ModelAttribute("Utilisateur") Utilisateur Utilisateur, HttpServletRequest request)throws ServletException{
                String password=Utilisateur.getPassword();
                Utilisateur.setPasswordUtl(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(password));
                List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
                roles.add(roleRepo.findById(2L).get());
                Utilisateur.setRoles(roles);
                utilisateurRepo.save(Utilisateur);
                request.login(Utilisateur.getEmail(), password);
                return "redirect:/";
            }
        }
````

this is the html code for the login page. I did not made this i just found it on the internet and tried to change it so it can matches my user entity however i think the error is here but i can not find it usually the thobject so it matches my enity and i also modify the thfield but as i said i couldnt know what to change. I am an html newbie tho.

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css"
            integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Registration Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" >
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img th:src="@{/images/logo.png}"  src="../static/images/logo.png" width="auto" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""/>
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/}" href="#">home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" th:href="@{/shop}" href="#">shop</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
    
          </ul>
    
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3 style="margin-top: 10px">Sign Up Now</h3>
        <p>Please fill out this to register</p>
    <!--
        @thymesVar id="utilisateur" type="almanara.almanaraplateforme.Utilisateur.Utilisateur"
    -->
        <form th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${utilisateur}" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" required placeholder="Your Firstname" class="form-control form-control-lg">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" required placeholder="Your Lastname" class="form-control form-control-lg">
          </div>
    
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" required placeholder="Password" name="password"
                   id="password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="telephone">telephone</label>
            <input type="number" name="lastName" id="telephone" required placeholder="telephone" class="form-control form-control-lg">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" required minlength="6" placeholder="Email" name="email" id="email"
                   aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with
              anyone else.</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="adresse">adresse</label>
            <input type="text" name="adresse" id="adresse" required placeholder="adresse" class="form-control form-control-lg">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="emploi">emploi</label>
            <input type="text" name="emploi" id="emploi" required placeholder="emploi" class="form-control form-control-lg">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="region">region</label>
            <input type="text" name="region" id="region" required placeholder="region" class="form-control form-control-lg">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="secteur">secteur</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" id="secteur" required placeholder="secteur" class="form-control form-control-lg">
          </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
          <span style="margin-top: 10px">Already have an account <a class="linkControl" href="./login.html"
                                                                    th:href="@{/login}">Login here</a></span>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There are no getters/setters for the field.

Comment: no i just did not show them in the code but there are getter and setters

Comment: No there aren't. You are mapping to `password` (check the `name` attribute of your form) but your setter/getter is for `passwordUtl`. So those don't match and won't bind. I suggest instead of a plain form to properly use the `th:field` from thymeleaf. That would have resulted in an error which would point you in the proper direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your error stacktrace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: rawPassword cannot be null
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(BCryptPasswordEncoder.java:107)
```

it simply means your password variable which you are passing to `bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(password)` is coming as blank.

```
Utilisateur.setPasswordUtl(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(password));
```

and the only reason it will be blank after your forms are getting submitted from frontend because of

- **You have not mapped your html attributes correctly with you Model attributes.**

and hence you are getting `null` for those attributes and you are passing null to the encoder and its throwing error.

**Correct your thymleaf html template as per below suggestions .**

Change the html as below to map the details in your `ModelAttribute` correctly.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" required placeholder="Password"
                       name="passwordUtl"
                       id="password">
</div>
```

You are defining the html tags as `name="password"` whereas it should be as per your attributes defined in entity class `name="passwordUtl"`.

Your entity class have diffrent named variables and you are using diffrent name in your html.

Correct all other `html names` as suggested above as per your entity class attribute names.